# Symmetric Matrix with Integer Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

What is the probability that a symmetric $3 \times 3$ invertible matrix has all integer eigenvalues? What if we limit the integer entries to have absolute values less than 10?

The probability of a random integer matrix having integer eigenvalues is small:

https://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/AAIMHNIE.pdf

So far, I've worked with two exceptional cases where the matrix had all integer eigenvalues. But, most of the time, the eigenvalues are irrational numbers.

Comment: With what probability distribution are you selecting your matrix?

Comment: I suppose uniform...?